# How to connect ASP.NET project with SQL Server database table in Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created simple database table in Visual Studio 2015 called `Users` and updated it.

[image]

I want to connect it with my project, so after I fill in my text fields and press 'Sign Up' button, it can get saved to database. I am aware that I'll have to use string connections and other stuff to connect it, but how do I first connect this project with `web.config` ?

[image]

I have seen people dragging this table to Registration form code, so it would automatically create a connection with web-config, but it didn't work for me.

How do I reference my database from `web.config` correctly ?

Comment: Depends where your database is stored. Is it sitting in your solution somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I created table in Visual Studio using SQL Database. I haven't used sql management studio. If that's what you mean.

Comment: It's not. When you create a database, the MDF file; which is your database (as shown in your screenshot), is stored somewhere. The connection string would need to know where that file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on MyDatabase.mdf and in the properties panel you will see the Connection String.  Copy that into the web config in the ConnectionStrings node:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="[Paste Connection String Here]"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Also apologizes to the @KSib, I've just started ASP.NET so don't understand quite lot of terms. : )